# The Java debugger returns "the system class loader does not define the appendToClassPathForInstrumentation method or the method failed"

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have an issue while trying to debug any file. Console pops out this :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51080,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\Błażej-PC\.IdeaIC2019.3\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Błażej-PC\IdeaProjects\Choinka\out\production\test;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" VERSJA14TEST.Main

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51080', transport: 'socket'
Unexpected error (103) returned by AddToSystemClassLoaderSearch

Unable to add C:\Users\B�a�ej-PC\.IdeaIC2019.3\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar to system class path - the system class loader does not define the appendToClassPathForInstrumentation method or the method failed
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, appending to system class path failed
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51080', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any fixes known?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyii4.png)

Comment: It looks like debugging is disabled by the VM you are trying to connect to, either because it's missing necessary libraries or because it's been purposefully disabled.  You'll have to find who made this thing and ask how they deployed it.

Answer (score 1):

[IDEA-236445](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-236445) is likely the case. It should help if you relocate IDE system directory to some other location on your disk without non-ASCII symbols in the path, [see this guide](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207240985).

Comment: Actually, [IDEA-250572](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250572) seems more relevant here.