# FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

when I want to debug a program.I met this error.
I can run my project correctly.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56587', transport: 'socket'
Unexpected error (103) returned by AddToSystemClassLoaderSearch
Unable to add C:\Users\΢Ц\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar to system class path - the system class loader does not define the appendToClassPathForInstrumentation method or the method failed
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56587', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Java debugger returns "the system class loader does not define the appendToClassPathForInstrumentation method or the method failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61293646/the-java-debugger-returns-the-system-class-loader-does-not-define-the-appendtoc)